# Calculate the credit amount the employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll calculate the amount of employee performance:

```
select Job_Id, Sum(money1) as m1 from T1 where Job_Id='8'
group by Job_Id
```

Then I calculated the amount of his salary(in other Table = T2):

```
select Job_Id, Sum(money2) as m2 from T2 where Job_Id='8'
group by Job_Id
```

Now, I will get the following: `m1 - m2`

How?

Comment: You will get or you want ? m1-m2

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque I want ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

```
select (select Sum(money1) from T1 where Job_Id='8') - 
       (select Sum(money2) from T2 where Job_Id='8')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what you want:

```
SELECT job, m1-m2 FROM 
(
SELECT T1.Job_Id AS job, Sum(money1) as m1, Sum(money2) as m2 
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 
ON T1.Job_id=T2.Job_id 
WHERE T1.Job_Id='8'
group by T1.Job_Id
)
```

Comment: when i test your command get this error : Incorrect syntax near ')'

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH T1 AS 
( 
  SELECT 

    SUM(Money1) as Total 
  FROM M1 
) 
SELECT SUM(Money1 - Money2)
FROM T1 INNER JOIN M2 
ON M2.Job_ID = T1.Job_ID 
where M2.JOB_ID = 8
```

Comment: when i test your command get this error : Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: CTE starts with ';' and you need to close the braces '()' in the query i think